# Summarize mean and confidence intervals in R with dplyr and conditional statements

Tags: r, dplyr, confidence-interval

My `df` is like the below one: `x` and `y` variables with 0, 1 and NA values, and `z` variable is a numeric one with value range from 0 to 5. I want to measure **conditional mean** for those `1` instances in `x` and `y`, and normal mean for `z` values, with their respective confidence intervals.

```
df <- tribble(
  ~"name", ~"region", ~x, ~y, ~z,
  "A", "reg1", 0, 1, 1,
  "A", "reg1", 1, 1, NA,
  "B", "reg1", 1, 0, 4,
  "C", "reg2", 1, 0, 2,
  "B", "reg2", 0, NA, 0,
  "C", "reg1", NA, 0, 5,
  "C", "reg1", 0, 1, 2,
  "B", "reg1", NA, 1, 3,
  "B", "reg2", 1, NA, NA,
  "A", "reg2", 1, 1, 1,
  "A", "reg2", 0, 1, 4,
  "A", "reg2", 1, 1, 2,
  "A", "reg1", 0, 1, 3,
)
```

I would like to have a final tidy table with columns like this (just for illustration I put two rows):

```
df1 <- tribble(
  ~"name", ~"region", ~"Indicator", ~"mean/prevalence", ~"Upper interval", ~"Lower interval",
  "A", "reg1", "x", 33, 176, -110,
  "A", "reg1", "z", 2, 14.7, -10.7,
)
```

My problem is to how organize my `dplyr` verbs. I did it like this but it is wrong because of the number of population `n()` that were considered in each interval calculation (they are all the same length).

```
df %>%
  group_by(name, region) %>%
  summarise(
    meanX = mean(x == 1, na.rm = TRUE)*100,
    nX = n(),
    Xlower_ci = mean(x == 1)*100 - qt(1- 0.05/2, (n() - 1))*sd(x == 1)/sqrt(n()),
    Xupper_ci = mean(x == 1)*100 + qt(1- 0.05/2, (n() - 1))*sd(x == 1)/sqrt(n()),
    meanY = mean(y == 1, na.rm = TRUE)*100,
    nY = n(),
    Ylower_ci = mean(y == 1)*100 - qt(1- 0.05/2, (n() - 1))*sd(y == 1)/sqrt(n()),
    Yupper_ci = mean(y == 1)*100 + qt(1- 0.05/2, (n() - 1))*sd(y == 1)/sqrt(n()),
    meanZ = mean(z, na.rm = TRUE),
    nZ = n(),
    Zlower_ci = mean(z) - qt(1- 0.05/2, (n() - 1))*sd(z)/sqrt(n()),
    Zupper_ci = mean(z) + qt(1- 0.05/2, (n() - 1))*sd(z)/sqrt(n()),
  )
```

If I could produce the upper table then I could use `pivot_longer()` to reach to `df1` which is the ultimate result.

Comment: Can you explain the calculation better? If we look at just the `name == "A"` and region == "reg1"` group, there are 3 rows, `x = 0, 1, 0` and `y = 1, 1, 1` and `z = 1, NA, 3`. In your desired result these numbers can be used with a `mean` to get both `66` and `2.3`. How?? What  exact calculation do you do to those inputs to get those 
"mean/prevalence" values?

Comment: 2.3 doesn't seem like a "normal mean" of `1, NA, 3`, and I don't have a clue what you mean by "conditional mean", and I don't see how to get `66` out of the `x` input. (Or does it use `x` and `y` together?)

Comment: Hey @GregorThomas. I want to measure the proportion of **value of 1** in each `name` and `region` for varibale `x` and `y`. These proportions are in percentage (number of value 1 per total instances of 1). For instance, in `B` and `reg1`, this proportion is 100% (one NA does not count). Then, I would like to measure the upper and lower intervals for these percentages.
For column `z`, I need mean not the proportion since there is no condition (conditions for `x` and `y`: only value 1 is of interest). `df1` is just a two-row example of what final table should look like.

Comment: values in `df1` table is just for better illustration. They are not based on `df`.

Comment: That's very confusing to provide sample data and desired output for different sample data. I'd strongly recommend making output match the input.

Comment: Based on your explanation in comments, I don't understand why you think `n()` doesn't work. It seems like you probably need to add some `na.rm = TRUE` arguments and figure out what you want to do when there is only one observation (`sd()` will return `NA` if there is only one input), but `n()` seems just fine to me.

Comment: Maybe you want `sum(!is.na(...))` instead of `n()` to ignore missing values? Can't really tell...

Comment: @GregorThomas I've just asked another question here to clarify this matter. Sorry if it still is ambiguous for you what I want. In below question I used same `x` and `z` varibale as for `reg1` and `A' variable here. 
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75883730/mean-and-confidence-intervals-for-boolean-vectors-proportion-of-true-instances.com).